# Collection view as a sticky header in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, tableview, sticky

I'd like to know how would you create a collection view embedded in a table view like the one you can see in Tinder app while you browse through someone's pictures.

It's obviously only a paging enabled collection but I don't know how to make it sticky at the top while still scrollable.

[image: screenshot]

Thank you for your help

J.

Comment: Attach the image of your requirement if you can.

Comment: Thank you @PGDev I added to my post a detailed screenshot so you can see what I mean !

Answer (score 0):

it is embedded in a navigation controller, so the bar at the top is alway fixed. plus it is not a collection view embedded inside a tableview, that would be ridiculously redundant. It is just a CollectionView with animations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @andrewF ! So in Tinder for example it doesn't seem to be one collection view alone as the images can be scrolled horizontally while the profile info can be scroll horitonally. I suppose it's probably two collection views or one collection view embedded in a table view which would definitely be easier to manipulate seeing the insets but here is not the question. I wonder how they could do that zoom-in effect while using a paging-enabled collection view (which is actually pretty common in many popular apps). Do you have an idea how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `table view` `section header` for this.

1. Create a `UIView` with `UICollectionView` in it.
2. Make this `UIView` as the `section header` of table view section. This `UIView` will then stick to the top for that particular section when the table is scrolled.

Comment: Hi ! First of all thank you for your answer. This would indeed work perfectly to make it sticky at the top. The problem is, like you can see it on the Tinder app, I'd like that collection (or more exactly each image inside) to expand whenever the user scrolls up, keeping the image ratio, to create a zoom-in effect. Do you have an idea ??

Comment: Please attach the screenshot.

Comment: Just what you want : https://medium.com/@dineshk1389/pull-down-table-views-e33d4c85018b

Comment: Thanks unfortunately it's really different, because instead of showing a different view when user scrolls, it should only expand the image to create a zoom-in effect. I could actually achieve that effect using constraints, it worked with ONE image at the top of tableView, but it doesn't work when I try with a paging-enabled collectionView filled with images..

Comment: Do you want a a complete photo gallery at the top?

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I'm looking for. A photo gallery at the top that would show event pictures. That gallery would be a square shaped collection view (width = screenWidth, height = screenWidth) with pagingEnabled = true and horizontal scrolling. And when you scroll down it would zoom-In the picture to some extent (depending on the contentOffset.y)

Comment: The link I referred, in that you can create a view with collection view according to your requirements and the pull down behaviour can be the same as in the link. For photo gallery you can refer to: https://github.com/inspace-io/INSPhotoGallery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146317/discussion-between-jellyfish6-and-pgdev).